# What experiments confirmed Poynting's Theorem?

Tags: electromagnetism, experimental-physics, poynting-vector

Actually, I have two related questions.  The fist is the above question.  The second is, what experiments confirmed that $\varepsilon_0\left(\frac{E^2}{2} + c^2  \frac{B^2}{2}\right)$ is the electromagnetic energy density?

I have been looking all over the place, online for such answers, but search algorithms aren't the best at distinguishing between requests for historical background, and requests for theoretical explanations of a phenomenon.

Google scholar isn't much better because of paywalls.

Comment: [Here is an experiment you can do yourself](http://www.ph.surrey.ac.uk/newsite/preprints/Jefferies2004Nov10155325.pdf); *An Experiment on Power transmission, and the Poynting Vector *. For a historical answer, try the History of Science and Mathematics StackExchange.